# Not running on a RPi! error in ROS with Python

Tags: python, ros

I am having the issue where I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/pijoy/src/pijoy_node.py", line 13, in <module>
    GPIO.setup(LED_GPIO, GPIO.OUT)
RuntimeError: Not running on a RPi!
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rospy
from std_srvs.srv import SetBool
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
LED_GPIO = 20
def set_led_state_callback(req):
    GPIO.output(LED_GPIO, req.data)
    return { 'success': True,
            'message': 'Successfully changed LED state' }
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('led_actuator')
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(LED_GPIO, GPIO.OUT)
    rospy.Service('set_led_state', SetBool, set_led_state_callback)
    rospy.loginfo("Service server started. Ready to get requests.")
    rospy.spin()
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

I have already added my user to group GPIO and I have also done setup.bash. Still no avail.

Comment: Are you running on a raspberry pi? If not, try using [rosjoy](http://wiki.ros.org/joy) instead.

Comment: Yes i am running on a raspberry pi 4 ubuntu 20.04 @Adid

Comment: [This thread](https://github.com/gpiozero/gpiozero/issues/837) suggests checking your user is in the `dialout` group and restarting your RPi

Comment: not sure what this did but:
cd /dev
chmod og+rwx gpio*
Fixed it.
It was on the thread you linked so thanks @Adid

Comment: Same effect as adding your user to `dialout`, it allows your user access to the GPIO device.

Comment: Something else that might cause this error (in case someone comes across this thread). If you run a kivy app, removing `from kivy.core.window import Window` fixed it for me.